# Is it possible to deduce that $\sin(x)< x$ for $0<x<\pi$ from the fact that $\tan(x)>x$?

Tags: inequality

It is not difficult to individually prove that in the domain $0<x<\pi$, we have

$$\tan x > x \quad(A)$$

and

$$\sin x < x \quad (B)$$

However, I was wondering if it was possible to get result $(B)$ for free from $(A)$, or possibly visa versa.

Comment: $\tan(\pi/2+\epsilon)<0<\pi/2+\epsilon$.

Comment: $\tan x$ is not greater than $x$ for all $x$ in the interval $(0,\pi)$  It is in the interval $(0,\frac\pi 2)$  But, if you are hoping for something that will work for the rest of the interval I would start elsewhere.  $\sin x$ is the distance from the point on the unit circle $(\cos x, \sin x)$ to the $x$ axis which is less that the distance from said point to the point $(1,0)$ which is less than $x.$

Comment: Note that $\sin x=\tan x/\sqrt{1+\tan^2x}$ is an increasing function of $\tan x$ on $(0,\pi/2)$ hence it is doubtful that a lower bound for the latter can imply an upper bound for the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we restrict our attention to the interval $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, the inequality
$$\tan(x)>x\tag{A'} $$
implies, by termwise integration, that over the same interval
$$ -\log\cos(x) > \frac{x^2}{2}\tag{A'1}$$
$$ \cos(x)<e^{-x^2/2}<1\tag{A'2} $$
hold. By applying termwise integration again, we may easily check that $(A')$ implies 
$$ \sin(x) < x \tag{B'} $$
so $(A')\to(B')$. With the same approach, $(B')$ implies
$$ \cos(x) > 1-\frac{x^2}{2}\tag{B'1}$$
$$ \sin(x) > x-\frac{x^3}{6}\tag{B'2}$$
$$ \cos(x) < 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}\tag{B'3}$$
so from $(B'2)$ and $(B'3)$ we have:
$$ \tan(x) > \frac{x-\frac{x^3}{6}}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}}>x \tag{B'4}$$
since $\frac{\pi}{2}<\sqrt{8}$. It follows that $(B')\to (A')$, so $(A')$ and $(B')$ are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

if $x>0$ then $x=\int\limits_{0}^x1dt\geq \int\limits_{0}^{x}\cos(t)dt=\sin(x)$

Comment: if you want to make the inequality sharp notice both functions are continuous.

Comment: This doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: Or just differentiate $\sin(x)-x$

Comment: @SteveD that's essentially what I did.